# Why I need to call every function with async keyword for calling an API in modularized code

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I have just started with async and await and trying to convert all my callback syntax to async/await style.

One thing I could not understand is, why I need to every time prefix my function with async keyword.

Here is the example:

## APIQuery.js

```
makeRequest: async(options) => {
 try {
  var response = await(request(options1))
 }
 catch(err){
  console.log("Some error occurred");
  response = undefined;
 }
return response;
}
```

## MobileAPI.js

```
getMobileData: async modal => {
 var options = {method: 'GET', json: true,uri: 'https://example.com/mobile/'+modal}
 var response = await APIQuery.makeRequest(options);
}
```

## MobileService.js

```
getMobileDataService: async modal => {
 var response = await MobileAPI.getMobileData(modal);
}
```

## MobileController.js

Similarly again I have to use async and await combination to return response.

So my question is, is there a way to get rid of using this everywhere. Calling async await inside APIQuery.js is not enough?

Comment: Async/await it is just a syntax to write less code. If you dont put async then linter/compiler whatever will through an error at await key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) operator, you have to use `async` keyword before function declaration:

> The await operator is used to wait for a Promise. It can only be used inside an async function.

If you don't want to use `async` everywhere, you can continue using callbacks or Promises (`then`, `catch`, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

> So my question is, is there a way to get rid of using this everywhere.

You can't block. Period. As soon as you block, your server would become completely unresponsive to *all* requests until it's unblocked. For this reason, your code *must* be asynchronous.

Callbacks are a perfectly valid form of asynchrony, but `async`/`await` is easier to use, understand, and maintain.